# How can i change the sender name?

Tags: php, email

When i send an email, Gmail automatically sends the name from the email owner, lets imagine that your name is Chris and your email is chris@mail.com and you send an email, the receiver will recive this:

**Chris** - Subject - Message

And the email will be:

from: chris@mail.com

I want to change **name**, i created a input box to write the name that the sender wants, how can i join this to **from**?

I want to do that:

**Sender name** - Subject - Message

My code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$sendername = $_POST['sendername'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to      = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: '.$from.' ' . PHP_EOL;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Sender name" name="sendername" />
<input type="text" placeholder="from" name="from" />
<input type="text" placeholder="to" name="to" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am slightly confuse as to what you want. Which part of the chain can you control? i.e. are you sending the email with your script or gamil? are you receiving email with gmail or your script?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
$headers .= "From: $sendername <$from>".PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
$sendername = $_POST['sendername'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
```

to

```
$sendername = $_POST['sendername'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$from = "\"$sendername \" <$from>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$headers .= "From: $sendername <$from>".PHP_EOL;
```

Hope it helps! :)